# Using Function Expansion but Getting Different Answers

Tags: r

Can someone explain why I am getting different answers for the 5th order polynomial using these two functions? Shouldn't they be the same output?

```
library(MASS)

out1<-lm(accel~times+ I(times^2) +I(times^3)+ I(times^4)+I(times^5),data=mcycle)
out12<-lm(accel~poly(times,5), data=mcycle)
summary(out1)
summary(out12)
```

Comment: By default, `poly` computes orthogonal polynomials. Try adding the `raw = TRUE` option.

Comment: A warning message is returned " extra argument ‘raw’ will be disregarded "

Comment: I ask this question because I am not sure which method to use when "approximating 'f' with an estimated nth order polynomial"

Comment: Here is how to turn off diagonalization, if that's what you want: `lm(accel ~ poly(times, 3, raw=TRUE), data=mcycle)`.

Comment: Whether you use the orthogonal polynomials or the raw ones changes the regression coefficients and therefore their interpretation.

Comment: I see. Is there a convention for approximation or is either compatible (just with different interpretations)?

Comment: This is a different question from what you originally posted about, and also more complex. Now that you know that the difference is orthogonalization, you can perhaps start reading more about that here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258307/raw-or-orthogonal-polynomial-regression.